# Three JS - r58 not rendering exported JSON from 3ds Max 2014 or Python script - Deprecated file format line 686

Tags: python, json, three.js, webgl, 3dsmax

This issue pertains to: Three JS - r58

I'm trying to find a workflow that is successful for creating and rendering JSON files from models in the browser.

So far, I've used the Python tool doing that with OBJ files exported from 3DS MAX 2014 using the method described here:

http://bkcore.com/blog/3d/webgl-three-js-workflow-tips.html

I've also tried using the MAX script - Three JS exporter, making sure that I was using the same version of the exporter and Three JS described here:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/2831

I'm not sure if I'm missing something or if there is an issue with the build tools. The tools are working, the problem is that they are not rendering the object. I can't find any issues in the JSON format either. It looks correct.

Here is the link to the test site. This particular test is from the current Max script Three JS exporter:

http://3d.dreammachinestudios.com

This is the error I get in Chrome and Safari - "Deprecated file format (anonymous function) Line 686" :

```
THREE.JSONLoader.prototype.createModel=function(a,b,c){var d=new          
THREE.Geometry,e=void 0!==a.scale?1/a.scale:1;this.initMaterials(d,a.materials,c);         
(function(b){if(void 0===a.metadata||void          
0===a.metadata.formatVersion||3!==a.metadata.formatVersion)console.error("Deprecated            
file format.");else{var c,e,i,k,l,p,n,o,q,m,r,s,t,w,u=a.faces;p=a.vertices;var               
v=a.normals,A=a.colors,B=0;for(c=0;c<a.uvs.length;c++)a.uvs[c].length&&B++;for(c=0;c         
<B;c++)d.faceUvs[c]=[],d.faceVertexUvs[c]=[];k=0;for(l=p.length;k<
```

If I switch out the JS with the JSON in the loader function with an model from this current repo - r58, it will render. Not perfectly, there are some other parameters I would need to change, but it does render. I used the Stork.JS:

http://stork.dreammachinestudios.com

Comment: You are linking to three.js r48dev, which is more than a year old. Also, test with the non-minified version, so you can make sense of the console errors.

Comment: I'm linking to it to give an example of the issue, not to compare builds.

Comment: The test is with the non minified. I've tried both.